# PHPUnit Fatal Error with Selenium/Ubuntu

Tags: php, unit-testing, ubuntu, selenium, phpunit

I have gone through various tutorials/posts to install PHPUnit with Selenium on my Ubuntu system.  I believe I have everything setup as required:

```
/usr/share/php$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

So using the IDE I create my test, and save it for running, which appears to be setup as required.  So I run the test using:

```
phpunit /home/retrobadger/working_files/tutorials/phpunit/selenium1.php
```

But everytime I run it, I get the error below:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestSuite' not found in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php on line 394
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:124
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase::suite() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php:0
```

The file in extensions exists, and I have set very open priviledges to it.  The only things I can think of are that either my SeleniumTestCase.php is faulty, or that I need to require another file no other tutorials have suggested.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. I have little experience with PHPUnit so expect my mistake is a basic one.

Thanks for any advice you can give,
Dan

Comment: Selenium testing is basically a UI testing, which is independent of any languages such as PHP/Java. Since, php support is officially removed from Selenium, I would recommend to test this with a stable tests written in Java. This problem was faced by me, and so to remain on stable side for long term, i chose it to do in java henceforth

Answer (score 0):

Check that you include PHPUnit when you call tests.. either in php.ini, or with IDE that you run, or explicitly - right now it just can't find class.. which means that PHPUnit is not reachable. Try a simplier class, PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase

Comment: I have checked that the below 3 lines are in my php.ini file:
    `include_path = ".:/usr/share/php"
    include_path= " :/usr/share/php/PEAR"
    include_path=".:/usr/share/php/PHPUnit"`

Comment: right.. it has phpunit directory, but maybe IDE is missing autoloading  framework when it tries to execute tests, try explicitly requiring it at the beginning of test (and then maybe move it to bootstrap) `require_once "Framework.php"`

Comment: Sorry, I fear I am confused.  I am not using a testing/development IDE at present.  I simply export using the selenium FF add-on, and run it in terminal.  I ran  locate for Framework.php and have no such file setup on my local system.  From what I have read, in version 3.6 I do no need this file, as Autoload.php is automatically used.

Comment: Try naming your file same way you name class.. so not `selenium1.php` but `selenium1test.php` and thus `Selenium1Test` class

Comment: I have done this, but sadly no luck.  File now named 'selenium1test.php' and the class line is 'class selenium1Test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase'.  My test command in terminal is 'phpunit /home/retrobadger/working_files/tutorials/phpunit/selenium1test.php', and I get the same error as before upon running.  If it helps, I have pasted a copy of my php file into pastebin [http://pastebin.com/NW6QVasH]

Comment: Well it works fine on my machine (gets to selenium connection and fails there).. so it has to do with phpunit and paths. Suite file should be in `PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestSuite.php`. Try to reinstall phpunit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.  That file was there, I uninstalled it, and reinstalled PHPUnit and ran my file, it gave me some new errors, so I installed PHPUnit_Selenium, then got the original error.  So have to assume that there is a problem with the PHPUnit_Selenium file.  To confirm this I ran the attached test [http://pastebin.com/ZMLLUzzS] which ran fine, giving me the expected error.